# p-adic numbers and GCD

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory, prime-factorization

Given two numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, how do we prove that the $p$-adic number of $\gcd(a,b)$ is the same as the minimum for the $p$-adic number of $a$ and the $p$-adic number of $b$? Does this involve the Euclidean Algorithm at all?

Comment: Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. What does $p$-adic number of $n$ mean? Perhaps "consider $n$ as a $p$-adic number"? In that case, this seems false.

Comment: The $p$-adic number of $n$ is the largest exponent $a$ such that $p^a \mid n$, i.e. it is $p$'s exponent in $n$'s prime factorization.

Comment: The number you are referring to is th *$p$-adic valuation* of a number, not the $p$-adic number of the number.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps one could argue this using the Euclidean algorithm (I don't see how), but I would recommend proving it using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. First show that if $p^r \mid \gcd(a,b)$, then $p^r \mid a$ and $p^r \mid b$. Then show the converse of this statement. Now use that the $\gcd(a,b)$ is the *greatest* common divisor.